# Stored procedure (or better way) to add a new row to existing table every day at 22:00

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I will be very grateful for your advice regarding the following issue.

**Given**:

- PostgreSQL database
- Initial (basic) query

`select day, Value_1, Value_2, Value_3
 from table 
 where day=current_date`

which returns a row with following columns

```
Day         | Value_1(int) | Value_2(int) | Value 3 (int)
2019-11-14  |     10       | 10           |   14
```

It is needed to create a view with this starting information and add a new row every day based on the outcome of  initial query executed at 22:00.

The expected outcome tomorrow at 22:01 will be

```
 Day        | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3
2019-11-14  |    10   | 10      |   14
2019-11-15  |    N    |  M      |   P
```

Many thanks in advance for your time and support.

Comment: Firstly: why do you want to register the result of a query of database into this same database? This seems wrong if it is really the case. You can do other ways ;)

Comment: Where do the values `N` and `M` and `P` come from? Are those really strings?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your reply. N, M, P are dummy integer values. The real values will be available once the query   will be executed tomorrow. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: But how do you know which values should be inserted during the night?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right. I know the values for today. Therefore they are in the post. But I do not know what will be the result of query tomorrow, day after tomorrow. I expect there will be possibility to schedule a query execution every night and the outcome will be added to the table.

Comment: But if you want a job that inserts that row you have to know which values to insert

Comment: Regarding the part of your question about running the code at 22:00 every night, Postgres does *not* have a built-in `cron` like feature that's readily accessible. To run your job, you'll need some external scheduler to execute the query.